# Python Recording file and Auto-Generated data into text

Tags: python, text

I am currently writing a program that detects and generates data for all files inside a folder and then write them into a text file. Below is the portion of my code that deals with this:

```
file = open("directory name", "a")
file.write("[ '" + item + "', [ [ " + str1 + " ], ] ]," + "\n")
file.close()
```

In the code, item refers to file name, str1 is the data generated from item. Now problem is that if one item has multiple str1 in it, it will record the data in a separate line with item in front instead of simply writting it as an item with multiple str1 in one single line.

Please point me to the right direction. Also there is no telling how many str1 is inside one item beforehand because str1 is auto generated with another portion of the code. Thanks alot as always guys!

Comment: `str1.replace("\n","")`?